# How to convert each value of an array object into single string?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Array **Given**:

`const Collection = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 4 }]`

**Required String** should be:

`string = "1,3,2,4"`

I have tried to get from forEach() loop to join() each value and save it in a string variable.

expecting result should be a comma separated string.

Comment: `Collection.map(obj => obj.id).join(",")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `forEach`, but you would have to pair it with something else.

```js
const Collection = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 4 }];
var res = [];

Collection.forEach(function(item) {
    res.push(item.id);
});

res = res.join(",");
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

[The `forEach()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) doesn't return anything. Instead you want to [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) each element to its `id` property, and then [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) it:

```
const collection = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 4 }];
console.log(collection.map(x => x.id).join()); // "1,3,2,4"
```

Note that the `join()` method takes care of converting the numbers to strings and adding commas (`","`), which are the default separators.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBKA28CmwoEtwwLwwNoG8Y0ATALhgEYYBfAGhkJPIGYb7GyYAmNhozgCw0AugG4AUKEghkAOnggA5gAoEyVBjCyAtgEMADsoAe2AHwwjskgEpZAKxBowy69fHigA)